# Prove that $\frac{\sin(a)}{\sin(b)} < \frac{a}{b} < \frac{\tan(a)}{\tan(b)}$ where $0 < b < a < \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Prove the following:

> $\frac{\sin(a)}{\sin(b)} < \frac{a}{b} < \frac{\tan(a)}{\tan(b)}$ where $0 < b < a < \frac{\pi}{2}$

Hello everyone, I am trying to create some sort of function or maybe see an application of the mean value theorem, but I am just not getting it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you fix b and differentiate in a this might help you to proceed?

Comment: Hmm, okay I will think about that! Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something along the lines of for instance to prove the left most inequality have $f(x) = \frac{sin(x)}{x}$ or $\frac{sin(x)}{b}$?

Comment: I mean something like, rearrange to make the inequality $b \sin(a) < a \sin(b)$. Then put $f(x):= b \sin(x)$ and $g(x):= x \sin(b)$. Then check that $f(0) < g(0)$, and check that $f' < g'$ for $x \in (b, \pi / 2)$, which would give you want you want. This is the usual approach for proving such inequalities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and $\frac{\tan x}{x}$. You need to show that they are decreasing / increasing on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.