# Showing $\frac{\tan x}{x} \leq \frac{\tan y}{y}$ for all $x,y$ such that $0 \lt x \leq y < \pi/2$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

I was reviewing some old calculus notes and came across this question:

> Show that the inequality $$\frac{\tan x}{x} \leq \frac{\tan y}{y}$$
> is valid for every $x,y$ such that $0 \lt x \leq y < \pi/2$

This one stumped me a bit. Does anyone have any idea about how I can approach this without using graphs?

Much appreciated!

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/631918 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/719814 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/724012

Comment: $\sin x \cos x \leq (x) (1)$. Use this to show that derivative of $\frac {\tan x} x$ is non-negative.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\frac{\tan{x}}{\tan{y}}>\frac{x}{y} : \forall (0<y<x<\frac{\pi}{2})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631918/prove-that-frac-tanx-tany-fracxy-forall-0yx-frac-pi2)

Comment: This is a property of *convex* functions, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1834388.

Comment: Thank you, everyone!

Answer (score -1):

The function $t \mapsto f(t)=\dfrac{\tan t}{t}$ in increasing in the interval $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ so, when $y\ge x$, we have that $f(y) \ge f(x)$.